# For number N how to find x,y where x*y = N and |x - y| is minimum?

Tags: arithmetic

I want to find numbers x and y such that x*y = N and |x-y| is minimum.
For example;

```
7 = 7*1
 
15 = 5*3

16 = 4*4
```

Is there a fast way to find this?

Comment: In general, $x$ and $y$ will be the pair of factors closest to the square root of $N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the largest number $\le\sqrt{N}$ that divides N. Let it be $a$. Then the required solution is  $x=a$, $y=N/a$.

Comment: Thank you! This is it.